# How to deal with jquery div`s

Tags: jquery

Can you recommend me a way when is clicked on the second box to disappear and in its place to move the third box ?

You can see it here http://jsfiddle.net/q6t7W/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a class to the elements you want to be hide-able, and then target those for the click event..

example at http://jsfiddle.net/SmdCy/

so add a `class="hideable"` to the elements your want and use the code

```
$('.hideable').click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```